# Using NOT and OR together in Elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

This the query I used in elastic search to filter records that either satisfy one condition or does not satisfy other condition.

```
{
    "query": 
    {
        "query_string": 
        {
            "query": "(NOT col1: \"val1\") OR (col2: val2)",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
}}}
```

The problem is I am not able to write an equivalent syntax in nodejs to extract the information. We cant use must_not here as it is an OR condition

Answer (score 0):

You will make both conditions in should array, as, if anyone matches you will get the record in results, you will have to use `must match` and `must_not match`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "match": {
                "col1": {
                  "query": "val1",
                  "type": "phrase"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "col2": {
              "query": "val2",
              "type": "phrase"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```